# QGIS 2.2 on OSX Mavericks stuck in full screen mode

Tags: macos, gis, qgis

I toggled into full screen mode on QGIS 2.2 on my Mac, and now the menu bar won't show and I can't toggle out of it. From the documentation, it looks like it should toggle with F11, but it's not working. I've seen people having similar trouble on Ubuntu and Windows 7, but nothing for OSX. Any ideas? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just spent close to an hour with this problem- QGIS 2.2 on mavericks.  Really vexing!  I tried reinstalling (after trashing the previous version as instructed in the install notes), tried removing the hidden .qgis2 folder in the home directory, tried disabling all spaces on the machine (I started with 8 desktops), tried all permutations of Apple-F, ctrl-F, apple-shift-F, etc...

Finally, and simply, the answer was this:

F11 is documented as the toggle key, but in my mostly stock setup this was bound in MissionControl to 'display the desktop'.  I rebound that function to F1, and then with QGIS up, hit F11 (on my MBP I need to also hold the fn key otherwise it's 'volume down') and I was out of Full screen mode.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks. My set up was different, but this got me fixed. There is a bug in QGIS because the implementation of Toggling Fullscreen is largely broken: View > Enter Full Screen works, but then there is no Exit Full Screen (still says Enter Full Screen). And there is an item View > Toggle Full Screen [F11], but it only toggles on, not off.